# Open FTP files in elFinder without giving details

Tags: php, elfinder

I am using elFinder for manage my FTP files. But I want to open FTP files and folders without giving FTP details. I keep elFinder files on same FTP. Is it possible?

In connector.php:

```php
$opts = array(
// 'debug' => true,
'roots' => array(
    array(
        'driver'        => 'FTP', 
        'path'          => 'here i give path of folder', 
        'accessControl' => 'access'  ,
          'tmpPath' => '../files/ftp',// disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
                'defaults' => array('read' => true, 'write' => true),
                'disabled' => array('rename', 'rm' , 'copy' ,'cut','paste')
    )
)
  );
```

but when I used this. I get this error:

> Invalid backend configuration. Readable volumes not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.To open files we dont need to use ftp option in driver just use localfilesystem and give path of files according to server.

```
$opts = array(
   // 'debug' => true,
  ' roots' => array(
array(
    'driver'        => 'localFileSystem', 
    'path'          => 'path of the folder that you want to browse', 
    'accessControl' => 'access'  ,

            'defaults' => array('read' => true, 'write' => true),
            'disabled' => array('rename', 'rm' , 'copy' ,'cut','paste')
)
    )
        );
```